# Is it possible to create Non Earth map in openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I'm working on a little hobby project for a game, it has some information about locations that are non earth coordinates with extents of 99999999999999999 to -99999999999999999 might even be larger.

I have a few questions regarding such large coordinates.

1. Can openlayers handle such large coordinates
2. Would it be best to scale it down to fit lat lon coords to mimic earth coords
3. what would the maximum decimals be for lat long accuracy in openlayers if I cannot use the full non earth coordinates?

Comment: max extent determined by SRS.Why you want to use EPSG"4326" with bounds ( -180, -90, 180, 90) ?

Comment: I've been able to override it with a XY-M projection and it just works ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Numeric values like this will propably exceed javascript numeric mantissa size. 
   The maximum values that can be represented by Openlayers are Javascript numeric values.
   You can use several kinds of projections to fit better your map.
   I guess browsers can handle about 14digits of precision on a numeric value.
2. You should scale down number to the integer space for fine accuracy.